# jQuery Supersized - captions animation

Tags: jquery, html

I have some issues with supersized plugin. I want to animate captions (title):

```
$.supersized({
slide_interval  :   5700,
slides          :   [
 {image : 'image01.jpg', thumb : '', title : 'title1'},
 {image : 'image02.jpg', thumb : '', title : 'title2'}
 ]
});
```

Can someone tell me how to get title value and animate it by:

```
.animate({bottom:"100px;"})
```

and then hide it and show next title when slide is changing.

Answer (score 0):

Open **supersized.shutter.js** Find this line:

```
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length)
{
   (api.getField('title'))?$(vars.slide_caption).html(api.getField('title')):$(vars.slide_caption).html('');
}
```

and change to:

```
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length) {
   (api.getField('title'))?$(vars.slide_caption).animate({'opacity':.1}).html(api.getField('title')).animate({'opacity':1}):$(vars.slide_caption).html('');
}
```

Also you can use these variables:

```
api.options.slide_interval;
api.options.transition_speed;
```

For example:

```
if ($(vars.slide_caption).length) {
    (api.getField('title')) ? $(vars.slide_caption).animate({'opacity': .1}, {complete: function (){$(this).html(api.getField('title'))}}).stop(true,true).animate({'opacity': 1}, api.options.transition_speed): $(vars.slide_caption).html('');
}
```